# Read local .csv to containerized airflow

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, io, airflow

I am currently doing a project for my uni where I set up an ML-workflow in Airflow, containerized with docker and started via a docker compose file. The starting point should be a .csv file, which I have available locally (or on github).
I am not yet understanding how I can bring this .csv to airflow (I quickly realized that pd.read_csv does not work as I am obviously in the container when the function is executed).
What are my options and which one is best?

(Most tutorials I have found import their dfs directly from sklearn or kaggle but that is not an option for me.)

Thanks already!

Comment: You can use `-v` or `--mount` option on CLI when you start the Docker or `volumes` in docker compose.  These options will mount your volume in local machine to the Docker container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the csv file to the volume you are uploading to Airflow.

If for example your dags are uploaded that way:

```
    volumes:
        - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
        - ./logs-volume:/usr/local/airflow/logs
```

you can put your file directly under dags/file.csv

To check that your file has been loaded to your container, you have to run it and run the following:

```sh
docker ps
```

which will result in:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS         PORTS                                        NAMES
8bffd2dad332   airflow:latest   "/entrypoint.sh webs…"   About an hour ago   Up 6 seconds   5555/tcp, 8793/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   webserver_1
f65bf73811cb   postgres:9.6        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 7 seconds   0.0.0.0:53468->5432/tcp                      postgres_1
```

and then you can run:

```sh
docker exec -it 8bffd2dad332 /bin/bash
```

then you can just do an ls on your file:

```sh
ls dags/
```